# How to formulate dependency of $y$ on $x$ in $y=2x+3w^2-\frac{1}{z}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, terminology

In a multivariate expression, how would one call the dependency of one variable on the other. To be more specific, suppose we have
$$y=2x+3w^2-\frac{1}{z},$$
with $w,x,z$ independent variables. Does it make sense tot say $y \propto x$ or should we use other words?
I can't seem to figure out how this is done in literature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that y, a function of x, w, and z, is "dependent on x for fixed w and z". Notice y might not change at all when x changes, if w and y are also allowed to change.
We can quantify the dependence using the partial derivatives:
$y_x= 2$.  $y_w= 6w$. $y_z= \frac{1}{z^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

In the particular case in OP, you may say that $y$ varies partly as $x,$ partly as $w^2,$ and partly as $1/z.$

In general, almost every expression can be thought of as a polynomial, and then you can just use that phrasing -- at least as a first order interpretation.

But who does that? With complicated expressions we simply write them down; there's no need to use cumbrous words. Indeed, that's partly why we use the symbols -- they're most times more compact than natural language.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to math.sx!  You have a function $y = y(x,w,z)$ (read ‘function of $x$, $w$ and $z$ʼ). You can state that $y$ *depends linearly* on $x$. In practice, I’ve only seen the notation $y \propto x$ used for multivariate functions used in experimental applications, where in any case the dependence is heuristic, or approximate.  I don’t see any particular reason why you should *not* write $y \propto x$, however, so it’s really up to you and/or your style guide.